# Create unknown amount of objects in another object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have the following classes:

```
class DutyDay(
    val date: Date,
    val hasStby:Boolean,
    val standByStart: Time?,
    val standByEnd: Time?,
    val showTime: Time,
    val closingTime: Time,
    val dutyTime: Float
)
```

and another class which will contain object of the class above:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tour_table")
data class Tour(
    @PrimaryKey
    val day1: DutyDay,
    val day2: DutyDay?=null,
    val day3: DutyDay?=null,
    val day4: DutyDay?=null,
    val day5: DutyDay?=null,
    val day6: DutyDay?=null,
    val day7: DutyDay?=null,
    val totalHours: Float
)
```

Each instance of "Tour" will have a minimum of 1 DutyDay (hence day1 will not be null) up to a maximum of 7 DutyDays. A list of Tours will be stored in Room.

I made it this way so I don't have to declare 49 variables in Tour (7 variables per DutyDay times 7 DutyDays)...

Is this the proper way to do it? Are the day1 to day7 in the right place in the constructor of the Tour class or should they go into the body of the class (curly braces)? I just want to avoid trouble further down the coding when I realize I made a fundamental mistake in the beginning.

Sorry, Im quite new, thanks for your answers.

Comment: you can also use lists in room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of statically defining the days per tour, it might help to start over, because one should instead *properly* represent such a [one-to-many relationship](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many) with the `@Relation` annotation:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tours")
data class Tour(
    @PrimaryKey val tourId: Long,
    ...
)

@Entity(tableName = "days")
data class Day(
    @PrimaryKey val dayId: Long,
    val tourId: Long,
    ...
)

data class TourWithDays(
    @Embedded val tour: Tour,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "tourId", entityColumn = "dayId")
    val days: List<Day>
)
```

And the DAO method:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM tours")
fun getAllToursWithDays(): List<TourWithDays>
```

This would be a whole lot more flexible than what you have there (in terms of days per tour). The `totalHours` wouldn't need to be stored, as one can calculate them by SQLite domain aggregate. If you'd design a relational data-model, this might invalidate your approach and confirm this one.